# Как распарсить массив на JS jquery и на основе этих данных присвоить ячейке таблицы класс

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть таблица

```
<table id="myTable" class="table stripe table-bordered wrap"> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>
      </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
     <tr data-id="1" class="status">
       <td data-name="du_id" class="du_id"><div>значение</div></td>
       <td data-name="podriadchik" class="edit podriadchik"><div>значение</div><input value=""></td>
       <td data-name="du_name_v_zakaze" class="edit du_name_v_zakaze"><div>значение</div><input value=""></td>
       <td data-name="adres_v_id" class="edit adres_v_id"><div>значение</div><input value=""></td>
    </tr>
   <tr data-id="2" class="status">
       <td data-name="du_id" class="du_id"><div>значение</div></td>
       <td data-name="podriadchik" class="edit podriadchik"><div>значение</div><input value=""></td>
       <td data-name="du_name_v_zakaze" class="edit du_name_v_zakaze"><div>значение</div><input value=""></td>
       <td data-name="adres_v_id" class="edit adres_v_id"><div>значение</div><input value=""></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

из базы данных при помощи php получаю массив

```
[0 => {
       "id": 1
       "column": "id"
      },
1 =>  {
       "id": 2
       "column": "du_id"
      },
2 =>  {
       "id": 3
       "column": "podriadchik"
      },
3 =>  {
       "id": 4
       "column": "du_name_v_zakaze"
      }
]
```

Как распарсить этот массив с помощью jquery и присвоить каждой ячейке с data-name - "column" в строке "id"  класс "alert-success"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передать на сторону клиента json и в js его распарсить в объект js.
В PHP перед тем как отдать этот массив в ответ ajax нужно использовать json_encode(наш массив) и вам в js вернется json формат.
Далее в js нужно распарсить полученный json через var res = JSON.parse(json_res)
Ну а далее уже перебираем наш объект и присваиваем ему нужные каждой ячейке с data-name - "column" в строке "id" класс "alert-success"
`jQuery.each(res, function() {
   $('[data-name="'+res.column+'"]').addClass('alert-success');
 });`

Comment: Дело в том, что таблица выводится на сторону клиента с помощью контроллера Laravel:   
        return view('projects.index', [
                                                 'projects' => $projects,
                                                     ]);  и уже в представлении в цикле foreach выводится каждая строка таблицы.  Как можно поступить в таком случае?

Comment: @AndreyRusyaykin, как вы получаете данные JS для заполнения таблицы? Если через AJAX, то можно распарсить после возвращения данных после запроса, если сразу при генерации страницы, то зачем тогда jQuery и jS нужен? Можно сразу в PHP подставлять нужный класс.

Comment: Данные для заполнения таблицы получаю сразу при генерации страницы. Но подставлять в PHP для конкретной ячейки нужный класс не получается, т.к. идентификаторов уникальных у ячеек нет. Есть только у строк, которые в базе данных имеют свой id. А у ячеек id нет, они принадлежат экземпляру класса строки. Поэтому изобретаю, как можно добавить класс ячейке при изменении в ней данных.